# Hemispherical space filling hilbert curve

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, fractals, curves, space-filling-curves

First question here, sorry for any posting infractions.

I need to create/find/buy a hemispherical space-filling Hilbert(or similar) curve.
something similar to [Cube hilbert](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimages1.sw-cdn.net%2Fproduct%2Fpicture%2F710x528_182890_35112_1550596721_1_0.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.shapeways.com%2Fproduct%2F8QN95RPF2%2Fhilbert-curve&tbnid=l9a3ic8o3swwuM&vet=12ahUKEwiVp9zq3dDvAhXSQcAKHRLKBykQMygAegUIARCbAQ..i&docid=0ozgeIoHJF-drM&w=710&h=528&q=hilbert%20curve%20cube%203d&ved=2ahUKEwiVp9zq3dDvAhXSQcAKHRLKBykQMygAegUIARCbAQ)
but only filling a hemisphere.

And this might be impossible but I would like to keep spacing between lines even as they approach the center...

Would appreciate any info pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Perhaps the circular designs at [squircular.blogspot.com](https://squircular.blogspot.com/2016/01/hilbert-curve-on-circular-disk.html) could be a place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I still havent found a solution for a hemisphere, but for a full sphere the solution was normalizing my cube hilbert curve around the zero and then mapping it with the equations from ["Mapping cube to a sphere"](http://mathproofs.blogspot.com/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html)

The results:

[image: Cube hilbert curve]
[image: Sphere hilbert curve]
[image: Deeper sphere hilbert curve]